# How do I get Mobile Numbers using Delphi FMX Address Book component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Delphi 10.3.
Cross platform application.
Android & IOS.
I am using the TAddressbook component and the following code adapted from the Delphi code examples.
I am able to get the names and photos but cannot workout the syntax for the phone numbers.
The code fills the Listview with firstname / surname & image but the  Contact.Phones seems to be an array.

I found this in the documentation

```
Phones.AddPhone(TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '+33-6-46-51-3531');
So I need somthing like this
Phones.Extract(TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile); // Does not work.

procedure TformMain.FillContactList(Source: TAddressBookSource);
var
  I: Integer;
  Contacts: TAddressBookContacts;
begin
  Contacts := TAddressBookContacts.Create;
  try
    AddressBook1.AllContacts(Source, Contacts);
    ListViewContacts.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListViewContacts.Items.Clear;
      for I := 0 to Contacts.Count - 1 do
        AddListViewItem(Contacts.Items[I]);
        //AddListViewItem(Contacts.Items[I].Phones[0].Number)
    finally
      ListViewContacts.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Contacts.Free;
  end;
end;
procedure TformMain.AddListViewItem(Contact: TAddressBookContact);
var

  ListViewItem: TListViewItem;
  eMails: TContactEmails;
  phones: TContactPhones;
  c : TAddressBookContact;

begin


      phones := Contact.Phones;
      if Contact.DisplayName.Length > 0 then
  begin
  ListViewItem := ListViewContacts.Items.Add;
  try

     // ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Contact.Phones.Extract(TContactPhone.SupportedLabelKinds('Mobile'));
     // ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Phones.ExtractItem.LabelText. (TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '+33-6-46-51-3531');
      //ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Phones.ex ExtractItem AddPhone(TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '+33-6-46-51-3531');
      ListViewItem.Data['Text1'] := Contact.DisplayName;
      ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := '07446944654';  // from sample eMails.AddEmail(TContactEmail.TLabelKind.Work, edtWorkMail.Text);
//    TLabelKind = (Custom, Home, Mobile, Work, iPhone, FaxWork, FaxHome, FaxOther, Pager, Other, Callback, Car, CompanyMain,ISDN, Main, Radio, Telex, TTYTDD, WorkMobile, WorkPager, Assistant);
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2']  := c.Phones.First.LabelKind.Mobile.t;// Phones.IndexOf('Mobile');
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.ExtractItem('Mobile');
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.Extract.LabelKind('Mobile');
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.ExtractAt.LabelKind.Mobile;//('Mobile');
//    phones := Contact.Phones.ExtractItem.LabelKind.Mobile; //.TLabelKind.Mobile;// .Phones.Extract(Mobile);
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := phones.ExtractAt.LabelKind.Mobile;// Extract.LabelKind.Mobile;// ExtractItem.LabelKind.Mobile;//  Contact.Phones.Extract('Mobile').ToString;// Phones.Extract.TLabelKind.;
//    ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := phones.Extract.LabelKind.Mobile;//  Contact.Phones Items[0].TLabelKind. .Number;// .Items[0];
      ListViewItem.Data['Image3'] := Contact.PhotoThumbnail;

    ListViewItem.Tag := Contact.ID;
  finally
    ListViewItem.Free;
  end;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: I couldn't add my code in the original post as it stated ' looks like spam'. The code is 1750 chars so cannot fit in here. How do I add my code to this conversation ?

Comment: Yes I've gone through the documentation. The reason I wanted to show my code was so you could see I'm not just asking without trying. This line works okay
ListViewItem.Data['Text1'] := Contact.DisplayName;

Comment: ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Contact.Phones.Extract(TContactPhone.SupportedLabelKinds('Mobile'));
ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Phones.ExtractItem.LabelText. (TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '+33-6-46-51-3531');
ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] :=  Phones.ex ExtractItem AddPhone(TContactPhone.TLabelKind.Mobile, '+33-6-46-51-3531');
ListViewItem.Data['Text2']  := c.Phones.First.LabelKind.Mobile.t;// Phones.IndexOf('Mobile');

Comment: ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.ExtractItem('Mobile');
ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.Extract.LabelKind('Mobile');
ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := Contact.Phones.ExtractAt.LabelKind.Mobile;//('Mobile');
phones := Contact.Phones.ExtractItem.LabelKind.Mobile; //.TLabelKind.Mobile;// .Phones.Extract(Mobile);
ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := phones.ExtractAt.LabelKind.Mobile;// Extract.LabelKind.Mobile;// ExtractItem.LabelKind.Mobile;//  Contact.Phones.Extract('Mobile').ToString;// Phones.Extract.TLabelKind.;

Comment: ListViewItem.Data['Text2'] := phones.Extract.LabelKind.Mobile;//  Contact.Phones Items[0].TLabelKind. .Number;// .Items[0];

Comment: You are quite right to wish to include your code in your q.  Use copy/paste to add it to your q, then select it and press Ctrl-K to lay it out correctly.

Comment: Code added to the orignal post

Comment: Documents link. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.AddressBook.TAddressBookContact.Phones.